# How can I query based on position to get Edit View displayed based on position

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to build an application which has basic CRUD operations. I am able to display the Detail view w.r.t the position of Item selected from List View. But when I try to display the Edit View from Detail View the same query which was used to display Detail View is producing exception. So I am trying to read all columns and display them as per the position.

I am using the below shown Query to display the Edit View. But the application is displaying only the contents of first row of the table irrespective of position clicked:

My Query is:

```
db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.UID,
                SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME, SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION, SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME, SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,columns , null  ,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();


            task = new Task(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                    cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));



        }


        return task;
```

Please help me and give me suggestions as how should I update my query to achieve my objective.

When I click on Task5 on list view, it displays the details of Task5, but when I select Edit button, I am getting Edit view of Task1 that is first row. Please help me. I am new to Android. Please teach me.

MY ADB log for the error mentioned in comments:

```
02-26 18:59:51.985    1504-1504/com.ms.t.tms D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-26 18:59:52.000    1504-1504/com.ms.t.tms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ms.t.tms, PID: 1504
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ms.t.tms/com.ms.t.tms.EditScreen}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at com.ms.t.tms.SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.getTask1(SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.java:146)
            at com.ms.t.tms.EditScreen.onCreate(EditScreen.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My table structure:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "DataTable";
    public static final String UID = "_id";
    public static final String TASK_NAME = "Task_name";
    public static final String CONTACTS = "Contacts";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String REMARKS = "Remarks";
    public static final String DATETIME = "Date";
    public static final String ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME = "EstCompTime";
    public static final String ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME = "ActCompTime";
    public static final String NOTIFY_TIME = "NotifyTime";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TASK_NAME + " VARCHAR(250)," + CONTACTS + " VARCHAR(250)," + DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR(250), " + REMARKS + " VARCHAR(250),"
            + DATETIME + " VARCHAR(250)," + ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), "
            + ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME + " VARCHAR(250), " + NOTIFY_TIME + " VARCHAR(250));";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Raw queries!
Cursor c =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SOMETHING WHERE name = ?", args);

read more in 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: I used a query as shown below:
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DataTable where _id =?" ,new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

I am getting Cursor out of bound exception. Can you please tell what mistake am i doing in where clause?

Comment: Can you send the log ?

Comment: I have posted the log.

Comment: Index start from 0 to n-1.
If you have 3 selections, the respective indexes will be 0,1,2

Comment: Sorry pardon me. I got what you said, but where am I faltering I did not get that. What change should I do to my where clause?

Comment: in you Task constructor, you may acessing a invalid index, since the index start from 0.
Try this : 

task = new Task(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7));

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing you are calling sqlite query one time and getting all data. If yes, then you have to store all data in arraylist.

Then after you can use those data on selection of item. If your selected position is 5 then get data from 5th position of arraylist of data.

Set data in edittext again when position change.

2. Another assumption, 
   If you call sqlite query on selection of position then you have to modify in your sqlite query. Add where clause condition. You will get data of selected position, then after set in edittext.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Yes exactly, I am not getting the exact Where clause. Can you please suggest me which type of where clause should I use.

Comment: I am getting cursor Index out of bounds exception for the same query. The log posted is the output of same query.

Comment: You are using "where _id =?" ,new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});". Here id should be your table row id from where you expecting data. In spinner how you populate data. Are you getting table row _id when you select any item from spinner?

Comment: Currently I have passed the variable String id as a parameter to the method. Later based on value of id I am trying retrieve the position. Do I need to make any change in that?

Comment: I am not using Spinner here. Its a form.

Comment: The id you are passing in parameter is it available in your table from which you are fetching data. Can you share your table structure and id which you passed in the string id ?

Comment: Updated post with table structure.

Comment: Have you checked table is created? if created then inserted data in table. Check your database created from path @ //data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>. In eclipse, Click DDMS-> Select File explored -> select above given path. Export db file, check in Sqlite manager table created and data inserted in it.

Comment: Yes Table is created, Records are getting Inserted, I am able to display list of inserted records. i am able to view detail of each record. But I am not able to view the edit page, When I pass Null  to where clause as specified in the question I get the edit view of first row.

Comment: I have to work now, but you can check this tutorial -. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/